# Harmonic functions on graphs

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In Kumagai's book *Random Walks on Disordered Media and their Scaling Limits*, he says that, given $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{d}$ and a symmetric Markov process $(Y_{n})$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ with transition matrix $P$, the function $$\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_{A}}) \, \mid \, \sigma_{A} < \infty), \quad \sigma_{A} = \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0} \, \mid \, Y_{n} \in A\}$$ is a solution of the Dirichlet problem $$(P - I)\varphi = 0 \quad x \in A^{c}$$ with initial data $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$.

In the proof, he simply says $$\varphi(x) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}} P(x,y) \varphi(y)$$ "by the Markov property of $Y$."

Is it really that simple?  I see that $\sigma_{A}$ is a stopping time, but it seems like it's still necessary to break the term $$\mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_{A}}) \, \mid \, \sigma_{A} < \infty, Y_{1} = y)$$ into cases $y \in A$ and $y \in A^{c}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author did not write  $\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_{A}})  \mid  \sigma_{A} < \infty)$, he wrote $\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_{A}}) :  \sigma_{A} < \infty)$. He doesn't mean conditional expectation, but simply expectation over 
the set $\{\omega: \sigma_A(\omega)<\infty\}.$ We may rewrite the definition as
$\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_{A}})  \,{\bf 1}_{\{\sigma_{A} < \infty\}})$.

For $x\notin A$,  $\sigma_A=1+\sigma_A\circ\theta_1$ holds $\mathbb{P}^x$-almost surely. This is the crucial 
 point. It says that in order to hit $A$ from $x$, the Markov chain has to take at least one step.

This implies that, for $x\notin A$,  $Y_{\sigma_A}(\omega)=Y_{\sigma_A}(\theta_1\omega)$ holds $\mathbb{P}^x$-almost surely. The chain's position at time zero 
 has no effect on the hitting place.

Therefore 
$$\varphi(x)=\mathbb{E}^{x}(f(Y_{\sigma_A})  \,{\bf 1}_{\{\sigma_{A}<\infty\}})
=\mathbb{E}^{x}([f(Y_{\sigma_A})\circ \theta_1]  \,{\bf 1}_{\{\sigma_{A}\circ\theta_1<\infty\}})
=\sum_{y\in\mathbb{Z}^d} P(x,y) \varphi(y).$$

Such manipulations will seem simple and natural when you've gotten more experience
with Markov chains, I promise!